# System.Net.Mail.MailAddress Validation

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, lotus-notes

I am working with the lotus notes smtp server and i need to send mails to lotus notes mail groups, which are not standard mail addresses, for example:

```
mail.To.Add("#Team Mailing List");
```

I know that the smtp is able to accept this, but how can i make .net play ball, anyone tried this?

I want to avoid using the domino interop if possible.

Comment: The accepted answer is a workaround. Would be good if someone knows how to do this for groups that don't have an "internet address".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lotus Notes mail groups should be referred to by their Internet Address item.  Have a look in your group document within the Domino Directory.  You should see a standard SMTP address in  the Internet Address field.  The domino router task will handle sending to the group based on that address.

Comment: I finally got to speak with one of the domino admins, at the compant i work at the default is to not provide an internet address, but he said they could be added, so now i'm happy, thanks!